# AnyLogic Model- Patient Scheduling Project

Tags: anylogic

I am currently working on a project to model outpatient appointment scheduling for a local hospital. The goal of this project is to model their current situation and then adjust different factors to reduce the wait time until the next available appointment. We are using AnyLogic to create the model. At this hospital the current system is as follows:

1. A patient calls and schedules an appointment with one of the hospitals 19 sub-specialties.

   - appointment will either be a first time consultation lasting 1 hour or a follow up appointment lasting 15 minutes.
2. Patient waits 1 week-6 months until their appointment date (based on sub-specialty)
3. Patient is seen by a doctor and then exits the system

We have approached the problem in two ways, the first was to attach the schedule to the resource pool which consists of the doctors for a single sub specialty. This would allow the schedule to change as the number of doctors change. The second approach was to attach the schedule to the source which consists of the patients entering the system. This better controls the flow of individuals into the system.

We are having difficulties figuring out how to configure the model so that it accurately shows the result of adding more doctors while still allowing the flexibility we need in scheduling different length appointments in multiple sub-specialties.

If anyone has experience with AnyLogic Scheduling, has dealt with a similar problem, or has any advice on how to proceed, I would appreciate the input.

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting question but I don't think this is in StackOverflow's remit: it is primarily a *simulation design* question, not a programming one. It is probably more appropriate posted on the AnyLogic LinkedIn Users group.

Comment: Hello bjewett, here I think your problem was adressed: http://www.anylogic.com/blog?page=post&blog=blog_EN&id=outpatient-appointment-scheduling you could watch the video and read the case-study. Plus, you could try and contact Michelle Alvarado who implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the number of resources you have according to a certain schedule...

In the schedule you need to you use integer type and then create your schedule based however you want. In the action you can use "value" as a variable that corresponds to the value of the current schedule value. The action in the schedule is activated everytime the schedule changes... so you can simply do resourcePool.set_capacity(value);

With this you have the flexibility to use different length appointments... You can use one different schedule for each sub-specialty